# C# regex to match a number in fourth line

Tags: c#, regex

I'm new to C# regex. I haven't been able to match the number in the fourth line (including a blank line on third line) using C# regex:

```
 <th>Total Members</th>
 <td>

    87
 </td>
```

Comment: @MehmetInce Please be more careful when you edit a post. The newline on line 3 should not be deleted from this question (did you even read the question?).

Comment: Use WebClient client.DownloadString() to read a big string. Yes, it's a single string with new line characters in it. I tried "<th>Total enrolments</th>\r\n.*?\r\n.*?\r\n.*?(\d+). It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"<th>Total Members</th>\s*<td>\s*(\d+)\s*</td>", RegexOptions.Multiline);
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: You forget to use close your string with `"` at the end. Like; `@"<td>\s*(\d+)\s*</td>"`

Comment: Thanks. It helps. But there are still many matches. But it would be a single match if the first line is considered. Can we do it?

Comment: @HongWang Please check the updated answer. Is that what you looking for?

Comment: Sabuj Hassan, Yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regular expression

```
^[0-9]{2}$
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your are going to parse html with regex.

I think you should use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead.